# How do I disable suggestions for plain text documents in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-files

I sometimes use VScode for plain text documents, however I'm constantly interrupted by suggestions to use particular words:

[image]

How can I stop this behavior for txt files? I would still like suggestions for code.

Via [this VScode bug and various related bugs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3137) I've attempted the following:

```
"[txt]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  }
```

However that does not stop the suggestions from happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer to this one myself, via [this screenshot on a related bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1657#issuecomment-283697916) - pasting it here to help others:

```
  "[plaintext]": {
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

1. command palette -> `Preferences: configure language specific settings`
2. under `suggestions`, go to `Editor: Quick suggestions`, and under the `other` item, change the value from `on` to `off`.

Note there were two other confusingly-named settings: `Inline suggest: enabled` and `Editor: Snippet suggestions`. I had no idea what they meant, but they were not relevant here.

Comment: This seems to have moved: now after your step 1 select [Plain Text], then in the tree: Text Editor> Suggestions, then under the heading "Quick Suggestions". "other" item.

Comment: `Inline Suggest: Enabled` is whether the suggestions appear as ghost text or not. The ghost text can be accepted by hitting tab.